# Dipole moment of sphere for given surface charge density

Tags: electrostatics

In the problem 3.30 of *Introduction to Electrodynamics by David J Griffiths*, the task is to calculate the dipole moment for given charge distribution, which is a surface charge *σ=kcosθ*.
In the solution manual, the writer does this as follows:
[image]
Now, my question is why z has been used to calculate this dipole moment? According to previous discussion, I thought we should use r, but that is not the case I guess. Kindly help!

Comment: r is an arbitrary direction which could point anywhere. Choosing the z-direction is convenient because it depends only on $\theta$. By choosing r you include the x- and y-directions as well, both of which depend on $\theta$ and $\phi$. It simplifies things to choose z and get rid of any term containing $\phi$ in the integral

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a surface charge density $\sigma$, the dipole moment is:

$$ \mathbf{p} = \int \sigma \mathbf{r} \, \mathrm{d}a $$

This is a vector equation, which means that it is equivalent to a set of 3 equations involving the components of both sides:

$$ \begin{align} p_x &= \int \sigma x \, \mathrm{d}a \\ p_y &= \int \sigma y \, \mathrm{d}a \\ p_z &= \int \sigma z \, \mathrm{d}a \end{align} $$

The author of the solution has pointed out that $p_x$ and $p_y$ are zero and quickly moved on to calculating $p_z$.